# Thinkpad x201 Tablet, rotating Screen

Tags: xorg, monitors, thinkpad

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on thinkpad x201 tablet. I have tested the tablet modus once and the played a bit with the buttons under the screen (so rotated the screen). But now at the starting the netbook the reversed screen has been some how set as the default position for the screen. does any ubuntu user know how to fix this back to the normal position? 
I appreciate any help[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RandR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) may fit your needs. You want to have a look at the `--rotate` option:

`xrandr --output LVDS --rotate left`

You can ask for output devices using `xrandr -q`.

Comment: hi user236012 thank you for your answer. this means that i could disable a specific rotation (for ex. to right?) And have you any idea why this has happened to my screen configuration? what could i have done wrong?

Comment: I don't know what the buttons under the screen are actually doing. Maybe you can "play a bit more" with the buttons to get the original rotation back. Anyhow, why do you think the rotation in your image is not the normal position?

Comment: I suggest reading the following wiki: [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2). Maybe you can find some options for `xorg.conf` which are related to your problem.